# Color Pairs in ncurses not using correct colors

Tags: unix, colors, terminal, ncurses, picolisp

I'm trying to use ncursesw6.1 (linked to PicoLisp). As far as I know, PicoLisp directly passes through values in such a way that the fact that I'm calling ncurses through a non-C language shouldn't be a factor[[1]](https://software-lab.de/doc/native.html). However, when I try to use color pairs (defined like this):

```
(curses "init_pair" NIL 1 *COLOR-SCHEME-TEXT *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 2 *COLOR-SCHEME-COMMENT *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 3 *COLOR-SCHEME-FUNCTION *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 4 *COLOR-SCHEME-VALUE *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 5 *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK *COLOR-SCHEME-COMMENT)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 6 *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK *COLOR-SCHEME-FUNCTION)
(curses "init_pair" NIL 7 *COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK *COLOR-SCHEME-VALUE)
```

It doesn't work. Instead, color pair 1, 2, and 3 are all displayed as the same color pair. Then 4 and 6 are displayed as `*COLOR-SCHEME-COMMENT` over top of `*COLOR-SCHEME-BACKGROUND-DARK` and 5 and 7 are displayed as the reverse of 4 and 6. This seems to have no logical relation whatever to what I've entered. Even more strangely, when I use non-custom colors (colors 0-7) it doesn't work either, so having defined these color scheme colors through `init_color` has nothing to do with it.

I've individually tested the colors with color pair 1, so I know that the colors are being initialized correctly.

What exactly is going on with `init_pair`?

P.S. I've genuinely sorry if the fact that I'm using Lisp makes this harder, I know its not a common language. It seemed like a good idea at the time, and its been fine so far...

**Edit:** I've receompiled libncursesw6.1 with `--with-trace` enabled, and this is the pertinent info from the trace file:

```
called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,1,10,8)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,2,12,8)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,3,11,8)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,4,13,8)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,5,8,12)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,6,8,11)
+ return }0
+ called {init_pair(0x1d74d00,7,8,13)
+ return }0
```

These are indeed the correct values, so the right values are being passed to `init_pair`. Although the custom colors are not the issue, for those who want to know, here's the `trace` file's info on the `*COLOR-SCHEME` colors:

```
started color: COLORS = 256, COLOR_PAIRS = 65536
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,8,216,228,252)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 8, 216, 228, 252)
+ + return }"\e]4;8;rgb:37/3A/40\e\\"
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,9,908,956,896)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 9, 908, 956, 896)
+ + return }"\e]4;9;rgb:E7/F3/E4\e\\"
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,10,968,968,968)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 10, 968, 968, 968)
+ + return }"\e]4;10;rgb:F6/F6/F6\e\\"
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,11,612,748,1000)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 11, 612, 748, 1000)
+ + return }"\e]4;11;rgb:9C/BE/FF\e\\"
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,12,508,252,340)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 12, 508, 252, 340)
+ + return }"\e]4;12;rgb:81/40/56\e\\"
+ return }0
+ called {init_color(0x1d74d00,13,612,136,272)
+ + called {tparm("\e]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\e\\", 13, 612, 136, 272)
+ + return }"\e]4;13;rgb:9C/22/45\e\\"
+ return }0
```

In addition, although I set the `wborder` function to use color pair 7, which according to the debug info should be color 8 over color 13 (which matches what I have in my code), the `trace` file says that it is *actually* using color pair five, which I don't use anywhere in the code:

```
+ called {wborder(0x1da6cd0,{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040},{' ' = 040})
using {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}, {' ' = 040 | {A_BOLD|A_COLOR{5 = {color8, color12}}}}
+ return }0
```

**So, what I conjectured above is what is, indeed, happening. Color pairs 5 and 7 are being displayed the same, even though the colors and the pairs are being *passed* correctly to ncurses.**

Comment: I'd check that by building my own ncurses shared libraries with trace enabled and using LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY path to see what the library does with the parameters.  For a quick check, **`ltrace`** may help to show the calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, PicoLisp is purely interpreted so `ltrace` doesn't work on my program. What info, exactly, can I expect from building ncurses with trace enabled?

Comment: A debug-trace (e.g., setting `NCURSES_TRACE` to **`0x224`**) shows the calls, their parameters and the return-values.  Given that, you could verify if the lisp code makes it way to/from the library properly.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot, thanks! I'll post the results to this question when I have them.

Comment: How do I enable a debug trace? I tried searching through the ncurses source code (6.1, downloaded from the homepage) to see if that was a constant variable, and it was not. According to GNU documentation, its an environment variable, but ncurses doesn't use it when I `export` it, does it need to be set when I make a custom compile of ncurses?

Comment: The debug-trace feature is compiled into the library when it's configured using `--with-trace`, and is turned on with the environment variable.  Offhand, I'd use [`--enable-trace`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L1200), [`--enable-widec`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L748) (for ncursesw).  The manpage mentions [NCURSES_TRACE](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_TRACE).

Comment: Thank you, I thought that's what it would be. I'll compile a custom version of ncurses and use that, I just didn't know what option it was that would compile it with trace support. Yeah, for some reason the manpage didn't seem very clear when I read it.

Comment: Okay, I've posted the debug info. That's a really cool thing, being able to debug ncurses like that. Never would've found that! (:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185739/discussion-between-thomas-dickey-and-christopher-dumas).

Answer (score 1):

According to @christopher-dumas, the problem was an [error](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44922622#44922622) in PicoLisp:

> Okay I figured out what the problem was
>   color-pairs was implemented incorrectly, because Picolisp only has a right-shift operation, and the operand order is the oppsite of what C uses. Apparently, the source where I took the origional implementation of color-pairs was wrong. For the new implementation, I copied it from lib_gen.c in the ncurses source code.
>   The new implementation is:

```
   (de color-pair (n)
       (& (>> -8 n) (>> -8 (- (>> -8 1) 1))))
```

In ncurses, the color-pair value is an 8-bit field in `chtype` or `attr_t`, defined in the [**`curses.h`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/2c459b90e9eddaecd5d55e9eaf7382a753ed198a/include/curses.h.in#L1106) header.  Here's a quote from the template (the `@cf_cv_1UL@` is substituted to handle very old compilers which did not permit a `UL` suffix for numbers):

```
#define NCURSES_ATTR_SHIFT       8
#define NCURSES_BITS(mask,shift) (NCURSES_CAST(chtype,(mask)) << ((shift) + NCURSES_ATTR_SHIFT))
...
#define A_COLOR     NCURSES_BITS(((@cf_cv_1UL@) << 8) - @cf_cv_1UL@,0)
```